# How do I control lwa arm using geomagic touch?

Tags: ros, gazebo, arm-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have already made URDF model of the lwa arm and its working in gazebo using ros_control. Now I need to control it using geomagic touch haptic device. How should I proceed now ? I know I have to make some sort of ros controller for mapping haptic device joint position to lwa's but how should I go about it. Any hints would be appreciated.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245257/how-do-i-control-lwa-arm-using-geomagic-touch-?/) by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2016-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a few options for mapping geomagic touch to control the arm. You can either try doing joint positions like you mentioned, or you could control the end effector position based on the movement of the geomagic touch. It really depends on how you plan on using it.

In either case, you need to make a joint controller. For the first scenario, this would just be joint positions based on the geomagic touch. In the second case you can create a joint trajectory controller in which you send valid trajectories to the controller. You would have to create these trajectories on your own or use some motion planning interface such as MoveIt!

Before doing this, I would make sure you can send a joint position to each joint controller and successfully move the model in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0